# How to assign data to a property of type collection using a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Consider I have a class model looks like:

```
public class Catalogue
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ItemName {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
}
public class CatalogueByGuid
{
    public string Guid {get;set;}
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    public List<Catalogue> Catalogues {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to fill the `CatalogueByGuid` with all the data needed:

```
CatalogueByGuid catalogueDetails = (from catalogue in _catalogueContext.Catalogue
                                     where catalogue.GuidId == guid //matching upon foreign key
                                        select new CatalogueByGuidModel
                                     {
                                        Guid = catalogue.CatalogueGuid.GuidId, //CatalogueGuid is parent table
                                        FileName = catalogue.CatalogueGuid.FileName, //CatalogueGuid is parent table
                                        Catalogue = //How to select this
                                     }
```

How do I select the `Catalogue` in the `select` as it is a list.

Comment: call [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: `catalogue.CatalogueGuid.GuidId` sounds horribly redundant and overengineered. It would help if you explain (or at least show) the classes/entities you're using, because the naming is odd and not particularly descriptive of its purpose or content.

Comment: From :select new  CatalogueByGuidModel To : select new CatalogueByGuid

Comment: Maybe: `Catalogue = _catalogueContext.Catalogue.Where(x => x.GuidId == guid).ToList();` ... Seems for data binding/visualizing purpose otherwise its an odd design.